# Adding values of the column that have the same data ID?

Tags: text-processing, scripting, columns

I want to prepare a uniform daily data from a mixed daily and sub-daily data by adding the sub-daily values and producing a uniform daily data. My sample input and desired out put data looks like below.

Input file:

```
date            Value
01/01/2000     2
01/01/2000     2
01/02/2000     6
01/03/2000     5
01/03/2000     4
```

Required output file:

```
date          Value
01/01/2000    4 (i.e. 2+2)
01/02/2000    6
01/03/2000    9(i.e 5+4)
```

Comment: You should start accepting answers for your questions: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

If the lines are in chronological order:

```
awk '
 NR==1{print;next}
 $1!=l && NR>2{print l,n;n=0}
 {n+=$2;l=$1}
 END{if (NR>1) print l,n}' < input.file > output.file
```

That is, output the count as soon as we see the first fields being different from the last line. That means we don't have to hold all the data in memory  and wait till the end to display it like in [Barun's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88319/22565) or [slm's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88325/22565) solutions. That also means the order is automatically preserved.

Comment: @ Stephane, Thank you. Perfect, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with AWK and its associative arrays:

```
awk '{ 
    if (NR == 1) { print $0 } 
    else { count[$1] += $2 } 
} 
END { 
    # Sort the items based on the date  
    n = asorti(count, indices)  
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {  
        print indices[i], count[indices[i]]
    }
}' < file_name
```

The `END` block is executed at the end when all the records have been processed.

The sorting of the array has been copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2458455/147021).

Comment: Note that the order of the lines is not guaranteed.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for pointing out! Updated with sorting.

Comment: @Barun, it is working, but it doesn't maintain the order of the date.

Comment: @Abraham That's strange! I get the dates in order after including `asorti`.

Comment: @Barun, I have this error massage: awk: line 12: function asorti never defined.

Comment: @Abraham Apparently `asorti` works with GNU AWK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16212450/147021 You can try `gawk` instead of `awk`, if available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` script:

```
$ awk '
  { a[$1]+=$2 }
  END{ for(val in a) printf("%s %s\n", val, a[val]) }
' <(tail -n +2 sample.txt)
```

However the order of the output will no longer be preserved with this approach. So long as the data is in date numeric order though, a simple `sort` at the end will realign the output.

#### Example

Assuming sample data.

```
$ cat sample.txt 
date            Value
01/01/2000     2
01/01/2000     2
01/02/2000     6
01/03/2000     5
01/03/2000     4
```

The above script will generate the results as follows:

```
$ awk '
  { a[$1]+=$2 }
  END{ for(val in a) printf("%s %s\n", val, a[val]) }
' <(tail -n +2 sample.txt)
01/02/2000 6
01/01/2000 4
01/03/2000 9
```

Running the output through `sort` will realign the data.

```
$ awk '
  { a[$1]+=$2 }
  END{ for(val in a) printf("%s %s\n", val, a[val]) }
' <(tail -n +2 sample.txt)|sort
01/01/2000 4
01/02/2000 6
01/03/2000 9
```

The header from the original file can be added back in thusly:

```
$ (head -n 1 sample.txt; awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(val in a) printf("%s %s\n", val, a[val])}' <(tail -n +2 sample.txt)|sort)
date            Value
01/01/2000 4
01/02/2000 6
01/03/2000 9
```

You can unroll this a bit so it's easier to read:

```
$ (
head -n 1 sample.txt
awk '
  { a[$1]+=$2 }
  END{ for(val in a) printf("%s %s\n", val, a[val]) }
' <(tail -n +2 sample.txt) | sort
)
date            Value
01/01/2000 4
01/02/2000 6
01/03/2000 9
```

#### UPDATE #1

Based on feedback from @StephaneChazelas in the comments, I've streamlined my example a bit more. Was able to eliminate the `tail ...` by moving it inside the `awk` block using this, (`NR==1{ next }`). This will skip the first line from `sample.txt`.

I've also moved the `| sort` inside the `END{...}` block. This will still `sort` the output generated by `awk` to realign the data based on dates. Since `awk` is now calling `/bin/sort` it's wrapped in double quotes.

```
$ awk '
  NR==1{ print; next }
  { a[$1]+=$2 }
    END{ for(val in a) print val, a[val] | "sort" }
' sample.txt
)
date            Value
01/01/2000 4
01/02/2000 6
01/03/2000 9
```

Comment: @sim, It works perfect! Thank you for helping

Comment: using process substitution that was is not useful. It's the same as `tail -n +2 sample.txt | awk...` and there's no point using `tail` here given that `awk` can easily exclude the first line by itself (`NR==1{next}`)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I see what you're saying with the `tail`, so I've moved that into `awk`, thanks. I see that I could potentially move the `head` into `awk` too, but then I'll no longer be able to use the `sort` after the `awk` block. Seems easier to keep that outside still?

Comment: You can `print | "sort"` in `awk`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks. That's still calling the executable, "/bin/sort" and not some builtin to `awk`, correct?

Comment: yes. `awk` creates a pipe to a new forked process, the first time it does `print | "sort"`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks for the edit. I see now with the `| "sort"` inside `awk` that the `head ..` can also now be moved in too. Prior I couldn't figure out how to get to do the sort when outside of the `awk` block, since that was sorting the headings too, which was undesired.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in Perl:

```
perl -ane '$.==1 && do{$first=$_; next}; $k{$F[0]}+=$F[1]; END{foreach (keys(%k)){print "$_\t$k{$_}\n"}}' file

01/01/2000  4
01/03/2000  9
01/02/2000  6
```

This approach has the advantage that it does not need the lines to be sorted chronologically.

Comment: Couple of issues with your example. It doesn't preserve the headers and also I think the OP wanted the chronology to be preserved, which your's doesn't.